# How to develop Tally ERP 9 plugins?

Tags: plugins, erp

I am trying to integrate Tally ERP 9 with a Web Service. Basically, I want to send a HTTP request to this web service when the user enters new **Sales** record into Tally. Basically I am trying to sync the sales data with the Web Service. I have learned that Tally can be integrated using XML or ODBC connection but what I'm specifically looking for is **triggers**. I've searched everywhere and read their docs but couldn't find anything on this. It would be much appreciated if anyone could point me in the right direction.